# err: Could not request certificate: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, puppet

- ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
- puppet-2.7.19-1.el5

I'm facing with the following error when starting puppet agent:

**`puppet agent --server=puppetmaster.domain.com --no-daemonize --verbose --debug`**

```
debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/tomcat_5.149.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/puppet.conf]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/tomcat_5.149.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run/agent.pid]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/run]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/tomcat_5.149.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/tomcat_5.149.pem]/mode: mode changed '0640' to '0644'
debug: Finishing transaction 23622871341440
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/tomcat_5.149.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/tomcat_5.149.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/tomcat_5.149.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: Finishing transaction 23622870227040
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
err: Could not request certificate: stack level too deep
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:58:in `Fail': Thread(#<Thread:0x2af83efcd378 run>) not locked. (Sync_m::Err::UnknownLocker)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:64:in `Fail'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:184:in `sync_unlock'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:232:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:650:in `uninterpolated_value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:800:in `each_source'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:797:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:797:in `each_source'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:647:in `uninterpolated_value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:646:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:646:in `uninterpolated_value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:682:in `value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:21:in `[]'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:65:in `[]'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/ssl/host.rb:297:in `wait_for_cert'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:407:in `setup_host'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:425:in `setup_agent'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:484:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:416:in `hook'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:407:in `exit_on_fail'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:69:in `execute'
    from /usr/bin/puppet:4
```

Since I'm not familiar with Ruby, could you help me please to solve this?

---

**UPDATE**

While it's working on the other agent with the same version, similar configurations:

```
[agent]
    hostprivkey = /etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/bk_6.142.pem
    certname = bk_6.142
    hostpubkey = /etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/bk_6.142.pem
    hostcert = /etc/puppet/ssl/certs/bk_6.142.pem
    ca_name = Puppet CA: bk_6.142        
    server = puppetmaster.domain.com
```

**`puppet agent --server=puppetmaster.domain.com --no-daemonize --verbose`**

```
notice: Starting Puppet client version 2.7.19
info: Caching catalog for bk_6.142
err: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Yumrepo[rpmforge] for Package[fsvs] at /etc/puppet/modules/utilities/manifests/install.pp:39
```

Can anyone give me some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me since ruby is throwing the overflow error 'stack too deep' and also failing to lock its own thread.  Is (was) the other agent running the same version of ruby?